# using sweetalert2 with custom callback / jquery selector

Tags: jquery, callback, sweetalert2

I'm not the best coder in the world, so the smallest things will cause me to stumble. I'm pretty sure this question has been asked before, but what I've found hasn't worked for me (or perhaps, I just have no clue!).

So I've only started using sweetalert2 to combine with my existing jquery functions (which has been in successful use for quite some time). I can get everything in sweetalert2 to work and my exisiting jquery callbacks to work ... but not together. Essentially, the order of events would be: Click Delete button -> Modal window opens -> Click confirm -> Handle Image Delete -> Close modal window -> Hide image thumbnail -> life is good. Alternatively the order for Closing modal window and hiding thumbnail could be swapped.

The stripped down html:

```
        <div class="recordC">
            <div><a data-fancybox="image_group" href="a/ path" class="showGalImg" ><img src="path/ to/ thumbnail-image"/></a></div>
             <li><a id="del-10792-01522" href="#" class="delbuttonC" >DELETE</a></li>
        </div>
```

Note that ids are dynamically generated and there are multiple div.recordC (one for each image)

The jquery / sweetalert2:

```
    $('.delbuttonC').click(function() {
    var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var photoId = 'id=' + del_id;
    deletePhoto(photoId);

    e.preventDefault();
  });

  function deletePhoto(photoId) {
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?", 
      text: "Are you sure you want to delete this photo?", 
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      closeOnConfirm: false,
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6 ",
      preConfirm: function() {
          return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "path/ to/ delete/ function",
        type: "GET",
        data: photoId,
        success: function() {
            swal({
                title: 'Deleted!', 
                text: 'Your file has been deleted!', 
                type: 'success'}).then(function () { 
                        $(this).parents(".recordC").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
                        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
                        });
        } // success:
      }); // $.ajax
          }); // Promise()
      },  // preConfirm:
    }); // swal
  } // deletePhoto
```

The modal window opens, the $.ajax works and the sweetalert2 success works. In my original jquery function, the callback also works after an image is deleted. But damn if I can get it to work with swal().

I have also tried:

```
        success: function() {
        swal('Deleted!', 'Your file has been deleted!', 'success');
        $(this).parents(".recordC").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
                    .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
    }
```

and I have swapped the order of the 2 callbacks and also moved my callback to after performing $.ajax (which is where it is in my current version that works). I have also changed $(this) to $("#" + del_id) ... and many more. All these permutations garnered from various questions asked across the internet! In every change I make, everything with sweetalert2 works and I manage to delete the image ... I just can't seem to get div.recordC to hide. I know there has got to be a very simple answer that I can't seem to work out :-(

Answer (score 0):

Solved my question ... nothing more than not pulling the var del_id into the function deletePhoto().